# How to create standalone python platform?

Tags: python, linux, macos, bundle

I would like to create zipped python platform bundle (with pyGTK library) for Mac/Linux/Windows. 
The purpose is to allow user to download customized version of eclipse with python libraries attached (such as pyGTK). Then user won't need to install python and pyGTK on his own.

Is it possible?

I tried create python platform with virtualenv, but it created symbolic links to original installation. After overwrite files (symbolic links with original files) it was not working.

The only way I found so far is to compile python from sources and install it by shell script. The question is if there exists some other way to do that?

Jakub

Comment: is py2exe what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think so... py2exe converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, but I need to have full python platform installed in custom directory

Comment: I think that cx_freeze is great tool for create standalone python app for linux & windows, probably for mac os (I didn't use mac os).

Comment: cx_freeze is similar tool to py2exe, it would not help

Comment: So you want a python script to install python when python isn't present?

Comment: Sorry, didn't fully read your question. May be possible way is make a zipped tarball archives with Eclipse and all python libraries for all OSes (may be self-extractor archives)?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I found sth for Windows: http://www.portablepython.com - after installation we can simply copy directory and then we can run pytho.